# Cython: cimport and import numpy as (both) np

Tags: python, numpy, cython, python-import

In the [tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html#adding-types) of the Cython documentation, there are cimport and import statements of numpy module:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
```

I found this convention is quite popular among numpy/cython users.

This looks strange for me because they are **both** named as **np**.
In which part of the code, imported/cimported np are used?
Why cython compiler does not confuse them?

Comment: Because `cimport` doesn't really import a (Python) module. It imports [(C) definitions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#the-cimport-statement). I don't know, but I could imagine that if you turn the second line into `cimport numpy` only, things would break: it may very well need the correspondonce between the actual Python module name as used in the script, and the definitions namespace.

Comment: @Evert You can also use `cimport numpy`, in the same way that one could use `import numpy`, it works just the same way, but `cimport` gives access to C functions or attributes under the imported module while `import` to Python functions or attributes

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`cimport my_module` gives access to **C** functions or attributes or even sub-modules under `my_module`

`import my_module` gives access to **Python** functions or attributes or sub-modules under `my_module`.

In your case:

```
cimport numpy as np
```

gives you access to Numpy C API, where you can declare array buffers, variable types and so on...

And:

```
import numpy as np
```

gives you access to NumPy-Python functions, such as `np.array`, `np.linspace`, etc

Cython internally handles this ambiguity so that the user does not need to use different names.

Comment: As a small addition: As hinted by @Saullo Castro, the Numpy C API does not offer all functions your Python Numpy offers. To find out what the C API can and can not do you can take a look at the `Includes` [folder](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Cython/Includes/numpy) in your Cython installation. There you will find the `.pxd` files Cython imports.

Comment: [Numpy C-API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html)