# Cythonizing a textblob autocorrect loop of a string array

Tags: python, cython, textblob, autocorrect

I have been trying to cythonize the following loop, however I can't seem to `cdef` the `np.array([],str)`. When compiling, array is not recognised as being part of numpy.

```
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

def arr_blob_corr(str_arr1):
    
    ph1=np.array([],str)
    
    for n1 in range(0,str_arr1.shape[0]):
        ph2=TextBlob(str_arr1[n1].lower()).correct().raw
        ph1=np.append(ph1,ph2)
        
    return ph1
```

I have tried

```
cdef np.ndarray arr2=np.ndarray(arr1,str)
```

and

```
cdef np.nrray arr2=np.array(arr1,str)
```

To no avail.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268228/cython-cimport-and-import-numpy-as-both-np - it's because you have to `cimport` numpy to use it in static types. I'm trying to find a better duplicate though

Comment: Don't spent too much time trying to statically type string arrays though - you'll find it difficult and won't gain much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by statically typing string arrays. However, lists of lists of strings may be the way to go in this situation.

Comment: There's very little advantage to setting the type of a variable to be `np.ndarray` - the advantages start to come when you tell Cython the type of the elements. Unfortunately it's quite hard to do that for an array of strings (which I think you're using?)

Comment: That was what I was hoping to use, yes.